# Nginx - proxy_pass to another internal location block

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, openresty

I am using Nginx to cache some responses. The backend that generates these responses, sets a common `Cache-control` header for all the responses. However, I need to cache some of the responses for a longer duration than the others. That is I need to modify the `cache-control` header before it is taken into consideration by the `proxy_pass` directive.

I am using the `ngx_lua_module` and want to modify the `Cache-Control` header in the `internal` location block using `header_filter_by_lua_block` directive. The intended config looks like the following:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass /actual;
    proxy_cache something;
}

location = /actual {
    internal;
    proxy_pass https://backend;
    proxy_cache off;
    header_filter_by_lua_block {
        -- modify cache-control header based on request/response parameters
    }
}
```

However I couldn't figure out a way to achieve this internal redirection via `proxy_pass`. I would appreciate any insight you have to make this work.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot  `proxy_pass` to a location, you can only `proxy_pass` to an upstream or an URL (which basically is non-declared upstream). So, answering to your question formally, you should `proxy_pass` to *localhost* with Host header set to the current `server_name`; but this probably will overcomplicate things.

**Instead** - looks like all you need to do is to get rid of the `location / {}` that you don't need and then rename `location = /actual` to `location / {}`.

I'd also say that you don't need lua at all - just remove the header you're getting from proxied web with `proxy_hide_header` and add your own with `add_header`.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking to pass control to another location block you should use internal redirects ([rewrite](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#rewrite)), not `proxy_pass`:

```
location / {
    rewrite ^.*$ /actual;
}
```

To modify upstream headers you can use [proxy_set_header](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_set_header):

```
location /actual {
    proxy_set_header Cache-Control '<your value>';
}
```

To modify downstream headers you can use [more_set_headers](https://github.com/openresty/headers-more-nginx-module#more_set_headers). It requires custom Nginx build with additional module, but it's really powerful in your case:

```
location /actual {
    more_set_headers 'Cache-Control: <your value>';
}
```

Taking into account the title of the question you can also make hardcore things like switching servers to handle clients traffic. I would NOT recommend it for such trivial tasks, but in rare cases it could help:

```
http {

    upstream internal_http_routing {
        server         unix:var/internal.sock;
    }

    server {
        # Internal interface
        listen         unix:var/internal.sock;

        location / {
            return     200;
        }
    }

    server {
        # Client-facing interface
        listen         443 ssl;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://internal_http_routing;
        }
    }

}

tcp {

    upstream internal_tcp_routing {
        server         unix:var/internal.sock;
    }

    server {
        # Client-facing interface
        listen         8443 ssl;
        proxy_pass     internal_tcp_routing;
    }

}
```